# motor working unintendly

Tags: mosfet, dc-motor, esp8266

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZKi10.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm having trouble getting these motors work. sometimes they work fine and sometimes they just run without giving any gate pulse at all. Is there something im missing in the circuit?.
The same circuit works perfectly when only one motor is connected. but sometimes the circuit works perfectly all of sudden even with both the motors. what can be cause of this behavior...
How can i make it a solid circuit for my project.

Comment: A couple of 4k7 pull down resistors from gate to ground should help to discharge the gates.

Comment: It may be wiser to have separate battery for reliable ESP communication and stable operation then shed motor load to another battery but with common gnd.

Comment: a seperate battery adds more space to the robot. Will it really solve my problem?, then i could go for two batteries.

Answer (score 3):

The 1117 regulator if it's anything like the LM1117 regulator, needs a bigger margin of input to output voltage for it to deliver current to the ESP8266 chip.

I suspect that when both motors are activated the voltage droop on the battery is passed through to the output on the 1117 regulator and this causes the ESP chip to reset or misbehave.

The LM1117 regulator requires typically 1.1 volts between input and output when supplying only 100 mA and if you look at figure 1 in the [TI data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm1117.pdf) it needs typically 1 volt when supplying virtually 0 mA.

Comment: I agree and suggest he uses some other regulator.  https://goo.gl/SsomTg  also make Wifi ready indicator

Comment: Is it okay to not use a voltage regulator ?

Comment: What working voltage range does the ESP chip require and, what range of battery voltages are possible. These answers will likely inform you that you need a regulator.